# Creating Java class to receive JSON object

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit

I am using RESTful API to retrieve some data over HTTP using retrofit2.

I have the following type of data, and I would like to store `replies` as object:

[image: Text]

The problem is, `replies` object is an empty string when no values (or fields) are present, i.e:

```
replies = ""
```

When there are fields, then `replies` object is given as:

```
replies = {
  "kind" : "Listing",
  "data" : {
      "key" : "data",
      "value" : {
        "modhash" : "",
        .
        .
        .
      }
    }
}
```

What is bothering me is the inconsistency between data types of `replies`, which is given as an object when nonempty and when empty, given as a String `("")`.

My dilemma is this: since Java is a statically typed language, I need to define what `replies` is **beforehand**, but I cannot define it as neither `Replies` nor `String` because of its inconsistency. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `replies` should contain an `{}` when its empty  .. You should change the API response not the parsing code .

Comment: If you can't change the API response, you might want to handle it in your code - by treating empty string as null. I don't know how to do it in retrofit, but in jackson you can do it like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60844488/jackson-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-exc-mismatchedinputexception-with-empty-s/60845316#60845316

Comment: @Smile Yeah, I don't think changing API response is viable.. thank you for your suggestion; I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change answer from your api, when `replies` is an empty you should send `replies : {}`